# Using mintty as default terminal on Cygwin and default shell as bash

Tags: terminal, cygwin

There is already one answered the question at [Best way to use a shell with Cygwin in Windows 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18405/best-way-to-use-a-shell-with-cygwin-in-windows-7). That is to start Cygwin with `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -`

With that `$SHELL = /bin/sh`

How can I launch mintty with `/usr/bin/bash` as default shell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several different ways to do it:

1. Specify `bash` as a command-line argument to mintty, as mentioned by Salton.
2. Set the Windows `SHELL` environment variable to /usr/bin/bash.
3. Make sure you have an /etc/passwd (see mkpasswd(1)) in your Cygwin environment, and set the shell for your UID to /usr/bin/bash. Cygwin doesn't supply a chsh or usermod command, so you'll probably have to edit the file by hand if you want to use this method.

From the mintty(1) manpage:

```
INVOCATION
   If a program name is supplied on the command line, this is executed
   with any additional arguments given.  Otherwise, mintty looks for a
   shell to execute in the SHELL environment variable.  If that is not
   set, it reads the user's default shell setting from /etc/passwd.  As a
   last resort, it falls back to /bin/sh.  If a single dash is specified
   instead of a program name, the shell is invoked as a login shell.
```

Comment: For me the 3rd approach, setting up the shell in /etc/passwd is the best, so that mintty can be run as `/path/to/mintty.exe [-i icon-file] -`, with the trailing `-` we get a login shell which I usually start a screen session.

Comment: `/etc/passwd` gets overwritten (sometimes?) when upgrading with Cygwin setup.

Comment: @ryenus what's the reason for that trailing `-`?  Talk about difficult to google..

Comment: @RoyTruelove to make it a login shell? Probably, please check bash manual

Answer (score 5):

You can launch `mintty bash` for bash to be default

Answer (score 4):

suppose this file name is mintty.bat,
double click this file will open a mintty terminal,
and with bash, path & pwd all settled down.

---

```
@echo off

C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe /bin/bash --login -i
```